# Ajax FileUpload Control appearance issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

Can't seem to figure out why the control isn't displaying properly. Also clicking the button does nothing as well.

Here is what it looks like in the designer

[image: What it looks like in the designer]

Here is what it looks like in the browser

[image]

```
<body>
<style type="text/css">
#header
{
    width: 547px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    height: 221px;
}
    </style>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:scriptmanager runat="server" id="scriptmanager"></asp:scriptmanager>
    <div>
        <div id="header">

            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Logo.jpg"/>
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Font-Size="XX-Large" Text="Master Import" ></asp:Label>
            <br /><br />
            <ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" runat="server"
                onuploadcomplete="AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete" MaximumNumberOfFiles="1" AllowedFileTypes="xlsm"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
```

web.config

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add name="AjaxFileUploadHandler" verb="*"
        path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd"
        type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadHandler, 
          AjaxControlToolkit"/>
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Can you provide a live URL to the problematic page?
Do you have any CSS stylesheet on the page that could break the appearance of the control?

Comment: @RumenJekov updated. No there is no live link. Internal site. I even moved it outside the div header and still the same results.

Comment: Check which classes should be on that control and with Inspect (browser) review which classes have. Overriden classes is the common cause for that.

Comment: Check for some global classes or CSS reset ones for input elements too.

Comment: I have started a new project with only the scriptmanager and AjaxFileUpload control and yields the same results.